# Code for getting the coordinates of points on the chart

Tags: java, algorithm, array, android, graphics

I am a beginner android developer. I am working on one of my applications. For this application, I wrote an algorithm that is needed to obtain data that is used to build a diagram. I have a list of objects (value, date).
For these objects, it is necessary to build a diagram either in the last month / two weeks / year.
If there are several values ​​for 1 date, then we take the orithmetic mean.
This code is written for my home project. I have a few requests:

1. Could you evaluate the quality of the code and say what is good and what is bad
2. I want to follow the principles of pure architecture. Therefore, I want to find out if I think that this code is a business logic.
3. I called this class ChangeHistoryGraphManager. Is this name correct?

I really want to learn how to write clean code, and so you are grateful to you for any criticism. Code:

```
public class ChangeHistoryGraphManager {
public enum TimeInterval {
    LastWeek(1, 7),
    LastTwoMonth(7, 60),
    LastYear(45, 365);

    private int dayPointInterval;
    private int allDay;

    public int getDayPointInterval() {
        return dayPointInterval;
    }

    public int getAllDay() {
        return allDay;
    }

    TimeInterval(int dayPointInterval, int allDay) {
        this.dayPointInterval = dayPointInterval;
        this.allDay = allDay;
    }
}

public List<Entry> getGraphDataPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> inputModels, TimeInterval interval) {
    if (inputModels.size() > 0) {
        ChangeHistoryUseCase.sortByDate(inputModels);
        return calculateGraphPoints(interval, inputModels);
    } else
        return new ArrayList<>();
}

private List<Entry> calculateGraphPoints(TimeInterval interval, List<ChangeHistoryModel> models) {
    List<TimeIntervalPoints> points = getPoints(models, interval);
    List<Entry> graphsPoints = getGraphsPoints(points);
    ArrayList<String> dates = getPointDates(points);
    DateValueFormatter.setDate(dates);

    return graphsPoints;
}

private ArrayList<TimeIntervalPoints> getPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> changeHistoryModels, TimeInterval interval) {
    ArrayList<TimeIntervalPoints> points = new ArrayList<>();
    int point = 0;

    Calendar startIntervalTime = getStartIntervalTime(interval);
    Calendar endIntervalTime = getEndIntervalTime(changeHistoryModels.get(point));

    for (int i = 0; i < changeHistoryModels.size(); i++) {
        if (addPoint(points, changeHistoryModels.get(i), interval, startIntervalTime, endIntervalTime, point)) {
            point++;
        }
    }

    return points;
}

private boolean addPoint(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points, ChangeHistoryModel model, TimeInterval interval, Calendar startIntervalTime, Calendar endIntervalTime, int point) {
    Calendar date = getCropDate(model.getDate());
    long modelTime = date.getTimeInMillis();
    long endTime = endIntervalTime.getTimeInMillis();

    float weight = model.getWeight();

    if (modelTime >= endTime) {
        return addNewPoint(startIntervalTime, points, date, point, weight, endIntervalTime, interval);
    } else {
        points.get(point - 1).getWeights().add(model.getWeight());
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean addNewPoint(Calendar startIntervalTime, List<TimeIntervalPoints> points, Calendar date,
                            Integer pointCount, float weight, Calendar endIntervalTime, TimeInterval interval) {
    if (startIntervalTime.getTimeInMillis() <= date.getTimeInMillis()) {
        points.add(new TimeIntervalPoints(new ArrayList<>(), date.getTime()));
        points.get(pointCount).getWeights().add(weight);
        endIntervalTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + interval.getDayPointInterval());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private Calendar getStartIntervalTime(TimeInterval interval) {
    Calendar startIntervalTime = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    setCropDate(startIntervalTime);
    startIntervalTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -interval.getAllDay());

    return startIntervalTime;
}

private Calendar getEndIntervalTime(ChangeHistoryModel changeHistoryModels) {
    long date = changeHistoryModels.getDate();
    Calendar endIntervalTime = new GregorianCalendar();
    endIntervalTime.setTimeInMillis(date);
    setCropDate(endIntervalTime);
    return endIntervalTime;
}

private Calendar getCropDate(long time) {
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.setTime(new Date(time));
    setCropDate(date);
    return date;
}

private void setCropDate(Calendar date) {
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
}

private List<Entry> getGraphsPoints(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {
    List<Entry> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        dataPoints.add(new Entry(i, points.get(i).getPointWeight()));
    }

    return dataPoints;
}

private ArrayList<String> getPointDates(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {
    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(points.get(i).getDate());

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM");
        String date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        dates.add(date);
    }

    return dates;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should review code that doesn't use [the new Java time API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review , as highlighted by @MaartenBodewes's comment, the main issue of your code is that there is no reason why you don't use [Java time API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). My suggestions are about common things I saw repeated in your code:

> ```
> ArrayList<TimeIntervalPoints> points = new ArrayList<>();
> ArrayList<String> dates = getPointDates(points);
> ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
> //methods returning ArrayList
> private ArrayList<TimeIntervalPoints> getPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> changeHistoryModels, TimeInterval interval) {}
> private ArrayList<String> getPointDates(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {}
> ```

Declare them as `List` :

```
List<TimeIntervalPoints> points = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dates = getPointDates(points);
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
private List<TimeIntervalPoints> getPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> changeHistoryModels, TimeInterval interval) {}
private List<String> getPointDates(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {}
```

If you have in a method a `if else` with one branch contain a `return` like this:

> ```
> public List<Entry> getGraphDataPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> inputModels, TimeInterval interval) {
>     if (inputModels.size() > 0) {
>         ChangeHistoryUseCase.sortByDate(inputModels);
>         return calculateGraphPoints(interval, inputModels);
>     } else
>         return new ArrayList<>();
> }
> ```

Rewrite it deleting the else branch, in this case I use the `Collections.emptyList()`:

```
public List<Entry> getGraphDataPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> models, TimeInterval interval) {
        if (models.size() == 0) { return Collections.emptyList(); }
        ChangeHistoryUseCase.sortByDate(models);
        return calculateGraphPoints(models, interval);

    }
```

If you iterate without using the index inside the loop for calculations like this loop:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < changeHistoryModels.size(); i++) {
>        if (addPoint(points, changeHistoryModels.get(i), interval, startIntervalTime, endIntervalTime, point)) {
>            point++;
>        }
> }
> ```

Rewrite it deleting the index i:

```
for (ChangeHistoryModel model : models) {
    if (addPoint(points, model, interval, startIntervalTime, endIntervalTime, point)) {
        ++point;
    }
}
```

I am sure that with [Java time API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) a lot of code would disappear including the enum `TimeInterval` and that would reduce significantly the number of lines of your code.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer . Java time API I can not use since it is available with api> 26 (Android 8). Could you answer 2 and 3 questions?

Comment: It’s also not clear to me why in this fragment                                                             for (ChangeHistoryModel model : models) {
    if (addPoint(points, model, interval, startIntervalTime, endIntervalTime, point)) {
        ++point;
    }
}                                                                                                                                you replaced point ++ with ++ point. What is the difference in this case

Comment: @Destroyer,  Hello, the answer to both your questions 2 and 3 is yes, name of the class is explicative about the use of it and why it has been codified and separation in  rules for managing data it is ok. For difference between preincrement and postincrement operator you can refer to [pre vs post in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) , lot of explanations and may other similar posts.

Comment: I understand the difference between pre-increment and post-increment, but in this situation it seems to me there will be no difference because we just increase point by 1.I apologize in advance if I'm wrong

Comment: You are correct, you can use the postincrement operator instead of preincrement operator and you obtain the same result.

Answer (score 0):

@dariosicily, Hi, I decided to rewrite the code using java time api. I am working with him for the first time, so I think there are problems in my code. Could you take a look at my new code?

```
public class ChangeHistoryGraphManager {

public enum TimeInterval {
    LastWeek(1, 7),
    LastTwoMonth(7, 60),
    LastYear(45, 365);

    private int dayPointInterval;
    private int allDay;

    public int getDayPointInterval() {
        return dayPointInterval;
    }

    public int getAllDay() {
        return allDay;
    }

    TimeInterval(int dayPointInterval, int allDay) {
        this.dayPointInterval = dayPointInterval;
        this.allDay = allDay;
    }
}

public List<Entry> getGraphDataPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> inputModels, TimeInterval interval) {
    if (inputModels.size() == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    ChangeHistoryUseCase.sortByDate(inputModels);
    return calculateGraphPoints(interval, inputModels);
}

private List<Entry> calculateGraphPoints(TimeInterval interval, List<ChangeHistoryModel> models) {
    List<TimeIntervalPoints> points = getPoints(models, interval);
    List<Entry> graphsPoints = getGraphsPoints(points);
    List<String> dates = getPointDates(points);
    DateValueFormatter.setDate(dates);

    return graphsPoints;
}

private List<TimeIntervalPoints> getPoints(List<ChangeHistoryModel> changeHistoryModels, TimeInterval interval) {
    List<TimeIntervalPoints> points = new ArrayList<>();
    int point = 0;

    LocalDate startGraphicsDate = getStartGraphicsDate(interval);
    LocalDate endIntervalTime = getEndIntervalTime(changeHistoryModels.get(point));

    for (ChangeHistoryModel model : changeHistoryModels) {
        if (addPoint(points, model, startGraphicsDate, endIntervalTime, point)) {
            point++;
            endIntervalTime = getEndIntervalTime(endIntervalTime, model, interval);
        }
    }

    return points;
}

private boolean addPoint(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points, ChangeHistoryModel model, LocalDate startGraphicsDate, LocalDate endIntervalTime, int point) {
    LocalDate pointDate = toLocalDateFromMilli(model.getDate());
    float pointWeight = model.getWeight();

    if (pointDate.isAfter(endIntervalTime) || pointDate.equals(endIntervalTime)) {
        return addNewPoint(startGraphicsDate, points, pointDate, point, pointWeight);
    } else {
        points.get(point - 1).getWeights().add(model.getWeight());
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean addNewPoint(LocalDate startGraphicsDate, List<TimeIntervalPoints> points,
                            LocalDate date, Integer pointCount, float weight) {
    if (date.isAfter(startGraphicsDate)) {
        points.add(new TimeIntervalPoints(new ArrayList<>(), date));
        points.get(pointCount).getWeights().add(weight);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private LocalDate getStartGraphicsDate(TimeInterval interval) {
    LocalDate startIntervalTime = LocalDate.now();
    startIntervalTime = startIntervalTime.minus(interval.getAllDay(), ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    return startIntervalTime;
}

private LocalDate getEndIntervalTime(ChangeHistoryModel changeHistoryModels) {
    LocalDate endIntervalTime = toLocalDateFromMilli(changeHistoryModels.getDate());
    return endIntervalTime;
}

private LocalDate getEndIntervalTime(LocalDate date, ChangeHistoryModel model, TimeInterval interval) {
    int currentDays = toLocalDateFromMilli(model.getDate()).getDayOfYear();
    int offsetDays = interval.getDayPointInterval();
    int days = currentDays + offsetDays;
    return date.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
}

private List<Entry> getGraphsPoints(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {
    List<Entry> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        dataPoints.add(new Entry(i, points.get(i).getPointWeight()));
    }

    return dataPoints;
}

private List<String> getPointDates(List<TimeIntervalPoints> points) {
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        LocalDate pointDate = points.get(i).getDate();
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM");
        String date = pointDate.format(dateFormat);
        dates.add(date);
    }

    return dates;
}

private LocalDate toLocalDateFromMilli(long milli) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(milli).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}}
```

Comment: Looks much better. You could check methods like [minusDays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-) or similar methods with word days and you can reduce the number of lines.